# Linux PHP - отследить цепочку серверов в запросе

Tags: php, post, curl, сеть, логирование

У меня есть сайт (ubuntu server, php, nginx). Он связан с другим сайтом и отправляет много POST запросов к API этого другого сайта. В день уходит примерно 10000 запросов. Из них 2000 неуспешных. Отправляю запросы с помощью CURl:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://api.other-site.com/api');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query([
'field1' => 'value1',
'field2' => 'value2',
...
]));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

При неуспешных запросах в переменную $error ложится строка:

> Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Я хочу выяснить, из-за чего такая нестабильная связь. Скорее всего нестабилен интернет-канал между моим сервером и сервером API.

В идеале было бы сделать скрипт, который бы отправил 10000 тестовых запросов с моего сервера на сервер API, и при этом подробно бы залогировал, через какие промежуточные сервера шел запрос, и на каком оборвался в случае неуспешного выполнения. Т.е., чтобы лог был примерно в таком виде:

```
2015-10-15 10:10:12 success
Request:
URL: http://api.other-site.com/api
METHOD: POST
PARAMS: field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3
123.236.100.240 server1.com
123.236.99.240 server2.com
123.6.100.240 server3.com
123.6.100.20 api.other-site.com
Response:
123.6.100.20 api.other-site.com
123.6.100.240 server3.com
123.236.99.240 server2.com
123.236.100.240 server1.com

2015-10-15 10:10:12 error
Request:
URL: http://api.other-site.com/api
METHOD: POST
PARAMS: field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3
123.236.100.240 server1.com
123.236.99.240 server2.com
123.6.100.240 server3.com CONNECTION RESET
NO RESPONSE
```

Этот скрипт будет запускаться в консоли сервера. Возможно такой написать на PHP или каком-то другом языке?

Comment: *залогировал, через какие промежуточные сервера шел запрос* — а откуда ваша машина получит эту информацию?

Comment: >> отправляет много POST запросов к API этого другого сайта. <<< чего???

Comment: @alexanderbarakin поэтому и спрашиваю, что не знаю способа откуда получить эти данные) знаю что есть в линуксе команда трейса, и ее можно вызвать из пхп через ф-ю system например, но она не совсем то что нужно.

Comment: `exec('traceroute api.other-site.com', $output);
var_dump($output);` Запрос дошёл, если последний ip это ip вашего сервера. Только проблемы с сетью если искать.

Comment: @AtOm, [принцип работы traceroute](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) — отправка множества icmp-пакетов с возрастающим [ttl-ом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) и отображение тех ответов, которые были получены от промежуточных узлов (от тех, что «соизволили» ответить). в принципе, ничто не мешает при формировании ipv4-пакетов указывать ttl, отличный от максимального, вот только http относится к прикладному уровню, который (по модели osi) находится на четрые уровня выше сетевого уровня (к которому относятся протоколы ipv4 и icmp).

Answer (score 1):

В итоге остановился на баш команде tcptraceroute

Эта команда как раз стучится на 80-й порт и показывает через какие промежуточные сервера проходит запрос.

Сделал баш скрипт, который переодически выполняет эту команду и логирует результаты. Запустил его на несколько часов, после чего проанализировал логи и выяснилось что запросы все таки сбрасывает API сервер к которому я обращаюсь. Т.к. через все промежуточные сервера зарос проходит стабильно, а при обрыве если посмотреть по логу он всегда происходил именно на конечном сервере. Так что команда помогла выяснить где именно обрывается запрос.

Код баш скрипта:

```
while [ 1 = 1 ]
do
  date >> ./trace-so.log
  tcptraceroute api.server.com >> ./trace-so.log
done
```